# 32bit Application run 64bit registry (with WOW6432Node)

Tags: c++, registry, 32bit-64bit

I have a 32bit application that must call `C:\Windows\System32\regedit.exe`, but instead it runs `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\regedit.exe`. How can I call the `regedit` in `System32`?

```cpp
void CSecureShellView::OnCommandsRegistry64bit()
{
    STARTUPINFO          si = { sizeof(si) };
    PROCESS_INFORMATION  pi;
    CString szExe;
    szExe = "regedit.exe";
        
    if (CreateProcess("C:\\Windows\\Sysnative\\cmd.exe", szExe.GetBuffer(100), 0, 0, FALSE, CREATE_NO_WINDOW, 0, 0, &si, &pi))
    {
        WaitForSingleObject(pi.hProcess, IGNORE);// optionally wait for process to finish

        CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
        CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
    }
}
```

The Condition returns True but `regedit` does not run.

Instead of `SysNative`, I put `System32`, but it does not work. In `szExe`, I put the string `"C:\Windows\regedit"`, but it does not work. And so on ...

Comment: have you tried `C:\\Windows\\Sysnative\\regedit.exe` instead of `regedit.exe`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/162309/how-to-launch-a-windows-process-as-64-bit-from-32-bit-code

Comment: `regedit.exe` is a GUI app, what is the point of running it without a window? If you just want to manipulate the contents of the Registry, there is a [Registry API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sysinfo/registry) for that purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this problem I use `ShellExecuteEx()` and `SHELLEXECUTEINFO`.

```
HRESULT result = CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED | COINIT_DISABLE_OLE1DDE);
SHELLEXECUTEINFO Sei;
ZeroMemory(&Sei,sizeof(SHELLEXECUTEINFO));
Sei.cbSize = sizeof(SHELLEXECUTEINFO);
Sei.lpFile = "C:\\windows\\regedit.exe";
Sei.nShow = SW_SHOW;
Sei.fMask = SEE_MASK_INVOKEIDLIST;
Sei.lpVerb = "open";
ShellExecuteEx(&Sei);
if (result == S_OK || result == S_FALSE)
    CoUninitialize();
```

For reference: [Launching Applications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/launch)

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to run `regedit.exe` via `cmd.exe`, why?  Any result you get will be for `cmd.exe`, regardless of what commands it executes.

Just run the Registry Editor instead of `cmd.exe`. However, there is a wrinkle.

The 64bit `C:\Windows\System32` folder does not have a `regedit.exe` executable. The 64bit `regedit.exe` is located in `C:\Windows` instead. If a 32bit process tries to run that executable directly, the 32bit `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\regedit.exe` will be run, which you don't want.

In order for a 32bit process to run the 64bit `regedit.exe`, it needs to run `C:\Windows\Sysnative\Regedt32.exe` instead, which is a stub that will run the 64bit `C:\Windows\regedit.exe`:

```cpp
void CSecureShellView::OnCommandsRegistry64bit()
{
    STARTUPINFO          si = { sizeof(si) };
    PROCESS_INFORMATION  pi;
    CString szExe = "C:\\Windows\\Sysnative\\Regedt32.exe";
        
    if (CreateProcess(NULL, szExe.GetBuffer(), NULL, NULL, FALSE, 0, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi))
    {
        WaitForSingleObject(pi.hProcess, INFINITE); // optionally wait for process to finish

        CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
        CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
    }
}
```

If `CreateProcess()` fails with `ERROR_ELEVATION_REQUIRED`, and you don't want to run your 32bit process elevated, then try using `ShellExecute/Ex()` with the `runas"` verb to launch `Regedt32.exe` elevated.

That being said, you should not hard-code the path to the `Windows` installation folder.  Ask Windows where it is actually installed, such as via `GetWindowsDirectory()`, `SHGetFolderPath(CSIDL_WINDOWS)`, `SHGetKnownFolderPath(FOLDERID_Windows)`, etc. And then you can append `Sysnative\\Regedt32.exe` to the end of that path.

Comment: First Thanks for your answer. I use the code but the if condition returns false so the rest of code does not run. I really confuse

Comment: @Yahya per the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessa): "*If the function fails, the return value is zero. **To get extended error information, call [GetLastError](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/errhandlingapi/nf-errhandlingapi-getlasterror)**.*" So, what does `GetLastError()` return when `CreateProcess()` fails?

Comment: If the string is "C:\\Windows\\Sysnative\\regedit.exe" the error message is "The System Can not Find The File specified." but if i change the path to "C:\\Windows\\regedit.exe" or "C:\\Windows\\system32\\regedit.exe" the message is "The requested Operation Requires elevation."

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It did not work so i solve my problem with another function.